# Concise way to deal with missing values

Tags: kotlin, option-type

I'm looking for a way to gracefully and concisely handle different cases in which one or another value may be absent. A concrete example use case could be to log which values were absent, as exemplified in the follow test case.

```
class MyArgumentsProvider: ArgumentsProvider {
    override fun provideArguments(context: ExtensionContext?): Stream<out Arguments> = Stream.of(
        Arguments.of(Optional.of("an A"), Optional.of("a B"), ""),
        Arguments.of(Optional.of("an A"), Optional.empty<String>(), "no B"),
        Arguments.of(Optional.empty<String>(), Optional.of("a B"), "no A"),
        Arguments.of(Optional.empty<String>(), Optional.empty<String>(), "no A and no B"),
    )

}

@ParameterizedTest
@ArgumentsSource(MyArgumentsProvider::class)
fun `missing values test`(maybeA: Optional<String>, maybeB: Optional<String>, expectedResult: String)
```

So basically I want to produce a string for each value (here A and/or B) if it is absent, and then concatenate all such strings produced with " and " into a single message.

I realized that this cannot be done with `Optional` as such, because the empty `Optional` does not "know" what it is missing.

Kotlin does not have an Either type, but there is the [Arrow](https://arrow-kt.io/learn/typed-errors/either-and-ior/) library that provides that.
Using this I can represent each value as either the value (Right) or the default "no ..." (Left). Then I can put them into a stream, filter for the Left instances, and concatenate them into the final output string:

```
    val result = Stream.of(
        eitherOrNoA,
        eitherOrNoB
    )
    .flatMap { it.left().stream() }
    .collect(joining(" and " ))
```

However, there still seems to be no really concise or idiomatic way to go from an `Optional` to an `Either` with either the Optional's value or the alternative like "no A".

Is there either a feature of Kotlin or Arrow or an additional library available that does the job?

Answer (score 0):

With Kotlin's extension functionality one may add an `eitherOr` method to `Optional`:

```
fun <D, T> Optional<T>.eitherOr(default: () -> D) = this.map { Either.right<D, T>(it) }.orElseGet { Either.left(default.invoke()) }
```

Using this I can now write:

```
    val result = Stream.of(
        maybeA.eitherOr { "no A" },
        maybeB.eitherOr { "no B" }
    )
    .flatMap { it.left().stream() }
    .collect(joining(" and " ))
```

which is pretty concise.